# Return to the main Form, and close the others, from a form that has other forms opened (C#)?

Tags: c#, forms

My problem it´s that I have Form1, that opens Form2, and then it opens another Form, I want to make a button on the last Form that returns to the main form and closes all the other.

Here´s how I programmed the Forms openings:

```
Form2 popup= new Form2();
this.Hide();
popup.ShowDialog();
This.Show();
```

And I did the same with the other Form, I tried doing something like this:

```
Form1 main= new Form1();
this.Close();
main.Show();
```

But it leaves all the other forms opened.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of all open forms in your application using `Application.OpenForms`. Then you can loop through them and close all the ones you don't want. Something like this:

```
foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms) {
    if (f.Name != this.Name)
        f.Close();
}
Form1 main= new Form1();
this.Close();
main.Show();
```

I have no means to test the code right now, but you can probably close the current form with all the others in the loop, so the code can be reduced to:

```
foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms) {
    f.Close();
}
Form1 main= new Form1();
main.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.Show();
this.Hide();
```

`this.Hide()` to the form you want to hide.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a reference of the MainForm through the constructor of every form you instantiate.

```
Form2 popup = new Form2(this);
this.Hide();
popup.ShowDialog();
```

And then keep a global reference of the MainForm on your Form2

```
private Form _mainForm;

// constructor of Form2
public Form2(Form mainForm)
{
    _mainForm = mainForm;
}
```

then with that reference you can call it anywhere. Also you can pass it to your third form

```
this.Close();
_mainForm.Show();
```

The benefits of doing it this way is that you do not lose any pre-defined settings on the main form because you're not creating a new instance, simply displaying it